# Have Area51 show what Beta phase is it's in (on Progress Bar on Home Page)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, beta-phase

Right now Area51 shows the steps of **define**, **commit** and **beta**.  How about we break up the beta section into **private beta** and **public beta**?  That way we don't have to click on them and try to login to find out what state they're in.

Comment: RE trying to log in on a private beta: [Mark a private beta as such *before* log in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63328/mark-a-private-beta-as-such-before-log-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area 51 now does a better job of indicating which is which, the text will be "beta" (not yet reached), "private beta", "public beta"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For those not already aware: `<joke>`

You could use this simple function:

```
public bool isPublic(Site s) {
    return s.daysInBeta() > 7;
}
```

That should give you whether or not a site is private or public.  (This hasn't been compiled or tested)

`</joke>`

But seriously, it's not that hard to tell based on the age of a beta site.

Comment: This is flagged as offensive? I guess with all the recent house cleaning this is probably the closest we can get. That being the case, **GO AWAY, TROLL**. Or something.

Comment: @Jon, wait, I'm a Troll now?  What is the world coming to?