# Add private / public threshold to the progress bar of a site in beta

Tags: feature-request, private-beta, beta-phase

I'm now kicking myself for not getting in on the Game of Go private beta, but I'm also curious as to how long the private beta will last. When I look at the the [list of proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta&page=2) it has a progress bar that tells me it's in private (perhaps in response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63285/have-area51-show-what-beta-phase-is-its-in-on-progress-bar-on-home-page)), but Game of Go has more progress (days?) than Spanish Language and Usage, which is already in public beta. It also seems that private betas used to be 7 days (from linked question), but Game of Go has had 21 days in private.

What determines when I site switches from private to public, and how many days does this typically take?